# Angular JS not able to update php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

I have created Web Application using Angular Js, PHP and mySql. There are many insert form are there in the application.

All inserts into the database are working pretty much fine.

My problem is: I'm not able to update my form using update mySql query.

I think problem is with form, but I'm not able to figure out what is actual issue.

Please check where is the bug

This my Html markup:-

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="dhmsEditSection">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="u in details.requirement_detail track by $index">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <form class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>New Project Requirement</legend>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Requirement No.</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled  ng-model="reqID" value="{{u.id}}" placeholder="Req. No. {{u.id}}">
                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Client Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{u.rClientName}}" ng-model="{{u.rClientName}}"  ng-model="rClientName"  >
                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Contact No.</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rContactNumber" value="{{u.rContactNumber}}"  ng-model="{{u.rContactNumber}}"  >
                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Company Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="{{u.rCompanyName}}"  ng-model="rClientName">
                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Email Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="rEmail" value="{{u.rEmail}}"  >
                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Requirement Information</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                         <textarea class="form-control"  ng-model="rRequirement"  >{{u.rRequirement}}</textarea>
                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>




                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updatedata()">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Controller:

```
dhmsApp.controller('dhmsEditSection',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.updatedata=function(){
        $http.post("include/editSectionBg.php",{'rClientName':$scope.rClientName,'rContactNumber':$scope.rContactNumber,'rCompanyName':$scope.rCompanyName,'rEmail':$scope.rEmail,'rRequirement':$scope.rRequirement})
            .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                alert("Data inserted successfully");
            });
    }
});
```

editSectionBg.php

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$reqID = $data->reqID;
$rClientName = $data->rClientName; // mysql_real_escape_string Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement
$rContactNumber = $data->rContactNumber;
$rCompanyName = $data->rCompanyName;
$rEmail = $data->rEmail;
$rRequirement = $data->rRequirement;

// syntax for mysql connect == "mysql_connect(host,username,password);"

include("connection_string.php");
include("connectionStringFetch.php");

mysqli_query($db, "update dhms_requirement set `rClientName`='".$rClientName."', `rContactNumber`='".$rContactNumber."', `rCompanyName`='".$rCompanyName."', `rEmail`='".$rEmail."', `rRequirement`='".$rRequirement."' where id='".$reqID."'");
?>
```

Comment: Please explain issue in more detail. Not clear what *"not able to update my forms"* means

Comment: ok i will do that right now

Comment: Add some error handling on both ends. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network also to see exactly what is end/received and status. Too many unknowns without you isolating which end the problem occurs in

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing to add `reqID` in your post data

`$reqID = $data->reqID;`